# How can I rotate a Canvas containing an Image by 90, 180, 270 Degrees?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I have an HTML5 canvas which contains an image. Now I want to rotate this canvas by x degrees.

What I did was:

```
function getRadianAngle(degreeValue) {
    return degreeValue * Math.PI / 180;
} 

var rotateCanvas = function(canvas, image, degrees) {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.rotate(getRadianAngle(degrees));
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  return canvas;            
}

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var cw = canvas.width = image.width;
   var ch = canvas.height = image.height;
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

   rotateCanvas(canvas, image, 180);
}
image.src = // some image url;
```

This code does not work correctly.

**How can I define a rotate function to rotate a canvas?**

Edit: I do not want to use css because I need the canvas for further processing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rotating the canvas can be done with CSS, but that might mess up your page design if the canvas is rectangular rather than square.

It's probably better to rotate your image on the canvas.

- Clear the existing canvas.
- Translate to the rotation point--x=image.x+image.width/2,y=image.y+image.height/2.
- Rotate.
- drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8uRaL/

BTW, the radians for your desired angles are:

- 0 degrees == 0 radians
- 90 degrees == Math.PI/2 radians
- 180 degrees == Math.PI radians
- 270 degrees == Math.PI*3/2 radians

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var radians=0;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/cat.png";
    function start(){
        animate();
    }


    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        ctx.rotate(radians);
        ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
        ctx.restore();
        radians+=Math.PI/180;
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not want to use css because I need the canvas for further processing.

Comment: Sure...see the addition to my answer.  Cheers!

Comment: Just to clarify what's different here with the working solution and what OP tried first: Any effects to the drawing (like translate and rotate) must be set up **before** it is drawn. Then after it is drawn with all effects to use on the drawing, use `restore()` to set back to default before continuing with other drawings. `context.rotate(...) does not rotate the whole canvas. It sets up rotation for what's drawn on the canvas after that point. Everything that was drawn previously will still be there when drawing again, so yo also need to clear the canvas before drawing again.